# Autogrow textarea height 0px?

Tags: angular

After init i have this:

```
  ngAfterViewInit(){
        this.autogrow();
    }
```

My function is this:

```
 autogrow(){
        let elements = (<HTMLScriptElement[]><any>document.querySelectorAll('.textarea'));
            elements.forEach(function(elem,index) {
                elem.style.height = (elem.scrollHeight) + 'px';
            });
    }
```

But problem is that i get height 0px for every textarea. Any suggestion how can i fix that?

Answer (score 2):

Why dont you set the height in the html using

```
<textarea
  [style.height]="YourGetterWhichReturnsHeightInString"
</textarea>
```

Getter returns the `scrollHeight`

Comment: i have multiple textarea how will know for what textarea will return what height?